# save values of arrays inside a state from different input fields

Tags: arrays, reactjs

i want to get the values from 5 input fields and save them inside a single state of arrays , how can i achieve that ?

```
const [features,setFeatures] = useState([]);

const handleChange = e => {
    setFeatures(prev => ({ ...prev, features, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }))
}

<Input type="text" name="features" label="Feature 1" value={features} required change={handleChange} />
<Input type="text" name="features" label="Feature 2" value={features} required change={handleChange} />
<Input type="text" name="features" label="Feature 3" value={features} required change={handleChange} />
<Input type="text" name="features" label="Feature 4" value={features} required change={handleChange} />
<Input type="text" name="features" label="Feature 5" value={features} required change={handleChange} />
```

Comment: You want to save it with index or input name?

Comment: with input values , i want to get that values and store them in a single array

Comment: These inputs are inside a `form` and you want to get them while the form is submitted, is that the case?

Comment: yes they are inside a form but the values of the first input when i type it uses the value for all inputs , i don't know how to store each values inside a single array

Comment: All your inputs have the same name and value that's why you modify one but all change together @RazorJhon

Comment: i know but how can i store all of them inside an array ? if i made the value feature[0] , [1] etc it store only 1 letter , how can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the below implementation

*Note that I hardcoded the array length and I'd assume your input array is static. If your input array is dynamic, you can use iteration for generating input fields. Besides that, I modified `Input` to `input` and `change` to `onChange` for the primitive input element. The button and form are for demo only.*

```js
const App = () => {
   const [features,setFeatures] = React.useState(new Array(5));

   const handleChange = (e,index) => {
      const updatedFeatures = [...features] //clone data
      updatedFeatures[index] = e.target.value
      setFeatures(updatedFeatures)
   }
   
   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(features);
   }

   return (<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}><input type="text" name="features" label="Feature 1" value={features[0]} required onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 0)} />
<input type="text" name="features" label="Feature 2" value={features[1]} required onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 1)} />
<input type="text" name="features" label="Feature 3" value={features[2]} required onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 2)} />
<input type="text" name="features" label="Feature 4" value={features[3]} required onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 3)} />
<input type="text" name="features" label="Feature 5" value={features[4]} required onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 4)} />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>)
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```